# Trying to create a 3D voxel terrain, and I am trying to create random seeds rather than the same seed multiple times

Tags: c#, random, 3d, perlin-noise, voxel

I am trying to figure out how to randomize my Perlin noise in C# but cannot find a way to do so with the code I currently have. Here is my code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PerlinCubeGenScript01 : MonoBehaviour {

public float perlinNoise = 0f;
public float refinement = 0f;
public int multiplier = 0;
public int cubes = 0;
public float darkness;


void Start () {


    for (int i = 0; i < cubes; i++) {

        for (int j = 0; j < cubes; j++) {

            perlinNoise = Mathf.PerlinNoise(i * refinement, j * refinement);
            GameObject go = GameObject.CreatePrimitive(PrimitiveType.Cube);
            go.transform.position = new Vector3(i, Mathf.Round(perlinNoise * multiplier), j);

            int cubeY = (int) Mathf.Round(perlinNoise * multiplier);
            Debug.Log(cubeY);

            go.GetComponent<Renderer>().material.color = new Color(1, 1, 1, 0f);

        }
    }
}

void Update () {

}
}
```

Comment: Aren't you picking the `0,0` point every time? You're not changing `refinement` variable...

Answer (score 0):

As long as Perlin Noise function allows you to pick any point in a 2D space, why not simply use a random number as your seed and start picking points from there?

```
void Start () {

    Random rnd = new Random();
    int seed = rnd.Next(Int32.MinValue, Int32.MaxValue);

    for (int i = 0; i < cubes; i++) {

        for (int j = 0; j < cubes; j++) {

            perlinNoise = Mathf.PerlinNoise(seed + (i * refinement), seed + (j * refinement));  
            // Note that if refinement never changes you are always picking the same point
            GameObject go = GameObject.CreatePrimitive(PrimitiveType.Cube);
            go.transform.position = new Vector3(i, Mathf.Round(perlinNoise * multiplier), j);

            int cubeY = (int) Mathf.Round(perlinNoise * multiplier);
            Debug.Log(cubeY);

            go.GetComponent<Renderer>().material.color = new Color(1, 1, 1, 0f);

        }
    }
}
```